# HTTP 404 Error, the webpage cannot be displayed

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-application

I've just started learning SharePoint 2013. I'm trying to create my first web application, it gets created but doesn't open. I have specified the port too. Is there something i should be aware of ?
I've displayed IIS Manager sites pic too.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is no error in creating Web Application. Based on this approach I am trying to help.

You need to create any Site Collection into it, Web Application cannot be opened directly. You can create a root level Site Collection.

As you are new to SharePoint 2013 you can go through [Create a Web Application and Site Collection in SharePoint 2013](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2012/create-web-application-site-collection-sharepoint-2013-preview/)

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: i have specified, title, decsription, username(checked it too). But the result was: "sorry, this site hasnt been  shared with you"

Comment: I guess you are logged in with Admin account which you have given while creating Application

Comment: If i have to login through different user, can you please let me know how & where can i find that option.

Comment: were you able to  created any site collection?